# Writing to a field On a web Page

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple HTML that on load will go to a URL and then put text in a textbox on the page. Below is the HTML that I came up with so far. It will open the page but will not enter the text that I put in.
Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>

<script>
document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="https://Bing.com/" style="display: none;" id="link">Link</a>';
document.getElementById("link").click();
</script>


<script>
function displayResult(element)
{
document.getElementById(element).value = "TEST";
}

}
</script>

displayResult("sb_form_q");

</body>

</html>
```

I tried the above code and I wanted it to put the text  "TEST" in the text box on the form.

Comment: Why not just use `window.location.href='https://Bing.com/';`? It's basically what's happening if your JS fires anyway to click the link

Comment: seriously? you cannot expect to run javascript defined in your page when the browser will be redirected to another page. The closest thing to that would be using iframes but I'm afraid it's too far from your expectation if you expected this to work.. and the comments really surprised me!

Comment: May be you want to try using this url : `https://www.bing.com/search?q=TEST` . It takes you to  [this page](https://www.bing.com/search?q=TEST)

Comment: Okay, I should first off I should mention I am not a web developer at all, I am a SQL VBA/VB.  My company asked me to find a way to do something.  So, I am just trying work my way through this code, and I think this could help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (in a `<script>` element) runs *in the current page*. Navigating to a new page will kill the currently running JavaScript program.

If you want to run some JavaScript on the subsequent page then you need to put the JavaScript *in that page*. You, clearly, don't control Bing, so you can't do that.

It would be a [major security problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you could do that.

---

The nearest you could come to this would be to write a browser extension that had permission to access `bing.com`.

Comment: Correct. For this precise reason, you can't even manipulate Bing in an iframe without explicit consent from them. That used to be possible in the early days of the www, but it isn't any more.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do this, would you have an example?

Comment: @EdwardWalsh — What "this" are you not sure how to do? Do you mean editing the source code of Bing (which I said was impossible)?

Comment: I am able to do this in a Vb. net application, but it is not exactly what we want.

Comment: A VB.NET application (a) must be installed explicitly and (b) isn't the user's regular browser with their regular cookies

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking for Bing searches, you will have to introduce parameters into your href="https://Bing.com/"
example: https://Bing.com/search?q=SEARCHTHIS

Comment: This works, but how would I do this if there was more than one texbox that I have to do this with on the form?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by textbox, explain what kind of behaviour you are expecting.
TextBox 1: (INPUT)
Expected: bing.com/search?q=(INPUT)
Is this it?

Comment: In my Vb.Net application, I am able to open a website like Bing Programmatically, find a textbox on the page and have it enter text in there. I do not want to use VB.net, it would be better if I could do something with HTML and or JaveScript.  But maybe that cannot be done?